# JavaScript replace issue with "vertical bar"

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace

I have the following code that replaces text from Microsoft Word with the proper characters.

```
message = message.replace(/[\u2018|\u2019|\u201A]/g, "\'"); // smart single quotes and apostrophe
message = message.replace(/[\u201C|\u201D|\u201E]/g, "\""); // smart double quotes
message = message.replace(/\u2026/g, "..."); // ellipsis
message = message.replace(/[\u2013|\u2014]/g, "-"); // dashes
message = message.replace(/\u02C6/g, "^"); // circumflex
message = message.replace(/\u2039/g, ""); // open angle bracket
message = message.replace(/[\u02DC|\u00A0]/g, " "); // spaces
```

The issue is, it replaces the vertical bar e.g: `|` with an apostrophe.

I'm guessing this is because I have the `|` within the replace code `message.replace(/[\u201C|\u201D|\u201E]/g, "\"")`. I presumed it was like an `OR` but obviously not.

Any idea how I can improve this code so that `|` is not replaced?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're putting your `\u` characters in a `[ ]` character class/group. This already does an implicit OR on the contained characters. Outside of character classes, `|` is OR, but inside it is a literal `|`.

Removing the `|` should work:

```
message.replace(/[\u201C\u201D\u201E]/g, "\"")
```

Alternatively, you could take them out of the character class, and keep the `|`:

```
message.replace(/\u201C|\u201D|\u201E/g, "\"")
```

You may decide that looks cleaner/easier to read (if one can say that about any regex). There are differences between the two methods if you wanted to do other kinds of matching, but for your purposes, these are functionally equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need alternations (represented by `|` characters) inside character classes:

```
message = message.replace(/[\u2018\u2019\u201A]/g, "\'"); // smart single quotes and apostrophe
message = message.replace(/[\u201C\u201D\u201E]/g, "\""); // smart double quotes
message = message.replace(/\u2026/g, "..."); // ellipsis
message = message.replace(/[\u2013\u2014]/g, "-"); // dashes
message = message.replace(/\u02C6/g, "^"); // circumflex
message = message.replace(/\u2039/g, ""); // open angle bracket
message = message.replace(/[\u02DC\u00A0]/g, " "); // spaces
```

Or use simple alternations instead of character classes:

```
message = message.replace(/\u2018|\u2019|\u201A/g, "\'"); // smart single quotes and apostrophe
message = message.replace(/\u201C|\u201D|\u201E/g, "\""); // smart double quotes
message = message.replace(/\u2026/g, "..."); // ellipsis
message = message.replace(/\u2013|\u2014/g, "-"); // dashes
message = message.replace(/\u02C6/g, "^"); // circumflex
message = message.replace(/\u2039/g, ""); // open angle bracket
message = message.replace(/\u02DC|\u00A0/g, " "); // spaces
```